# android holding on to memory when moving to a different Activity

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management

I am doing some pretty heavy lifting on my MainActivity (google maps, viewpager etc).  I understand why that is consuming so much memory, but when I move to the next activity, all of that memory is still being consumed and I can't figure out why.  I'm "killing" all of the objects that are consuming the memory before the next activity loads and then doing a System.gc() on the next activity.  As you can see in the screenshot, the memory usage (as shown in the monitor at the bottom) does not go down.  I've taken a snapshot to see what is using that memory, and there is only one thread which I've expanded in the screenshot.  None of my previous objects (google map, tile overlays etc) are still persistent but yet, the memory consumption has not gone down.  If I start debugging on this second activity, the memory usage is 1/100 of what it is if I go to this 2nd activity from my MainActivity.

I'm not sure what the dispatch():171, DdmServer etc are or why they're holding on to the memory as seen in the screenshot.  Any ideas?  If I continue in the app, I ultimately run into OOM which is what I'm trying to mitigate.
[image: Memory Usage on 2nd Activity]

Comment: "I'm "killing" all of the objects that are consuming the memory before the next activity loads" -- what exactly does "killing" mean in this context? "then doing a System.gc()" -- that does not do much. "Any ideas?" -- try turning off Instant Run, if you have not done so already.

Comment: instant run is off.  By killing the objects I mean this:             mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
            mLocationListener = null;
            locationHandler.quit();
            mTileOverlay.clearTileCache();
            mTileOverlay.setVisible(false);
            mTileOverlay.remove();
            mTileOverlay = null;
            map.clear();
            map = null;
as you can see in the screenshot, none of those object references exist in the heap, yet my memory usage is still very high.  If I don't "kill" them, the memory is the same and they're listed.

Comment: Generate a heap dump and examining it to determine what is holding onto what: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-hprof.html

Comment: I've tried getting a heap dump a few times and it doesn't ever seem to finish.  I see the dotted lines in my memory monitor in AS but it just seems to run perpetually.  Do I need to stop it (similar to Start Allocation Tracking) or do I just need to let it do it's thing and be patient?

Comment: It should run to completion on its own.

Comment: it never seems to finish and nothing is ever put into the "captures" tab when I try a heap dump.  I've also tried looking at the heap dump in Android Device Monitor but it doesn't show any of my methods/objects specifically...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122225/discussion-between-blair-holmes-and-commonsware).